# Assembly variable declaration meaning

Tags: assembly

I was wondering what var_10 = dword ptr -10h mean?
I know it mean i have a pointer to double word variable,
but what does -10h mean (how could a address be minus)?
the code is:

```
main proc near
var_10 = dword ptr -10h
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
and esp, 0FFFFFFF0h
sub esp, 10h

mov eax, offset aHelloWorld ; "hello, world"
mov [esp+10h+var_10], eax
call _printf

mov eax, 0
leave
retn
main endp
```

Comment: May you post the code in which you have seen this? It's probably an offset that has to be added to some index register, such as EBP

Answer (score 3):

The combination of `dword ptr` and `-10h` is odd indeed. The former suggest an address, the latter is a displacement or offset. In the code you posted, `var_10` is used just once:

```
mov [esp+10h+var_10], eax
```

I suppose the assembler will expand this to:

```
mov dword ptr [esp + 10h - 10h], eax
```

which is equivalent with:

```
mov dword ptr [esp], eax
```

So, the combination seems to make some sense, it's just that the individual components are weird.

The way this particular function handles the stack, is puzzling. Especially these instructions:

```
and esp, 0FFFFFFF0h
sub esp, 10h
```

What happens is that a block of 16 bytes is allocated on the stack, aligned to the nearest multiple of 16 bytes (potentially sacrificing a minor piece of stack space to get there).

Inside that 16-byte block, we fill the top dword (i.e. the 4 bytes closest to the new top of the stack) with a pointer to the 'hello world' string:

```
mov eax, offset aHelloWorld
mov [esp+10h+var_10], eax
```

The other 12 bytes in the 16-byte block remain uninitialized; they are most likely filled with random garbage.

Finally, we call `_printf`, which obviously finds the string pointer as its first parameter on the stack. That call should be fine.

In practice, you might do this as well:

```
mov eax, offset aHelloWorld
push eax
call _printf
```

The function as you posted it, seems totally prepared to take full advantage of a 128-bit architecture. Weird.

My best guess: this code was generated; not hand-written.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the points to give a comment so I'm leaving this as a solution. I'm fairly certain you can do direct addressing and don't need a register (ie ebp) to address from.  Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but the -10h, I believe, refers to the relative segment the code is loaded from with an offset of -10h for the data segment, code segment, or another segment. Someone tell me if I'm on the right track?
The code you seem to be missing is the data segment containing variables for db "hello world".